# How To Customize Switch Button with Shape?

Tags: android, android-button, android-styles, android-switch

How to make a customized switch button like this :

[image: Switch Button]

I had the idea to make it with "Jelly Bean Switch", but don't know how to make round corders, borders, and changing the font colors.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up coming across a library that does something similar to what you are looking for.

https://github.com/7heaven/SHSegmentControl

You can download the library and edit the features to your liking. 
It lookis like this:
https://github.com/7heaven/SHSegmentControl/blob/master/arts/arts1.gif

Comment: Thank's Eugene... seem's to be what I need ! :-)